# Is there an action of the strict infinity groupoid of the base on the chain groups of the fiber $C^*(F)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

I am trying to motivate using infinity categories by saying that there is no action $\pi_1(B,b_0) \curvearrowright C^*(F)$ where $F \hookrightarrow E \to B$ is a fibration.  Define the strict infinity groupoid $\Pi_\infty(B,b_0)$ to have one zero simplex.  The $n$ simplexes are singular $n-$ simplexes that map every edge to the basepoint $b_0$ of $B$.

Does $\Pi_\infty(B,b_0)$ act on $C^*(F)$?  Does it act on $F$?

Comment: Yup${}{}{}{}{}$